# request.get_json() is always NoneType

Tags: python, json, flask, getjson, jsonify

I just created a basic test application with flask:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def test():
    data = request.get_json()
    return str(type(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The return-Value here is always NoneType! Why doesn't the get_json method my Json-String?
I am using Postman to call the url with the json-String. Here is a Screenshot of how i did this:

[image]

Can anybody tell what i am doing wrong here? Is the information i gave you enough to figure that out or do you need something else?

Comment: Are you sending an `application/json` content-type header?

Comment: print the request and see where the data is.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json), `get_json()` requires the request mimetype (`Content-Type`) to be `application/json`.

> If the mimetype does not indicate JSON (`application/json`), this returns None.

Make sure you're sending the request with the `Content-type: application/json` header.

Comment: ah ok, i guess that is it, but where do i set this in PostMan? I see the content-type is ```text/html; charset=utf-8``` but i can't change that value

Comment: See [Postman's docs](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#sending-body-data): "If you use raw mode for your body data, Postman will set a header based on the type you select (e.g. text, json).
If you manually select a Content-Type header, that value will take precedence over what Postman sets." You seem to have `text` selected in your screenshot (right next to the "GraphQL" radio button).